# What's "CPU die temperature"?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

When I do this on my Macbook Pro:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc
```

It shows this:

```
CPU die temperature: 98.15 C (power)
CPU die temperature: 97.68 C (fan)
```

What's that?

Comment: It means that the Fan is doing its job in removing the heat from CPU. 98 C is on the low end for CPU

Comment: does 98 C here mean 98 degree celcius? what is good normal range

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_(integrated_circuit))

> A die, in the context of integrated circuits, is a small block of semiconducting material on which a given functional circuit is fabricated.

In this case, the Mac has sensors indicating the temperature of the central processing unit (CPU) as well as the exhaust fan.  Temperatures will vary based on the code being executed as well as environmental factors.

If your MacBook Pro's fans seem to be constantly running, or the device feels overly warm, consider performing [an SMC reset.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)